# Reloading the static files in Spark/Jetty-server

Tags: java, jetty, static-content, spark-java

I have a bit similar problem described here:

[Refresh static files served by SparkJava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32181702/refresh-static-files-served-by-sparkjava)

In my application user can upload the content to one folder that is also served to user with

```
Spark.staticFileLocation("/public");
```

feature. I've understood that SparkJava is reading the 'static' content from that folder only once at startup and it is not aware of changes there. Is it possible to ask Spark (or Jetty via Spark) to reload the changes in static folder?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move to `externalStaticFileLocation("/var/www/public");`

Comment: You can use a relative path such as `externalStaticFileLocation("src/main/resources/public/")` for development. You can make use of a argument(--dev) to switch between `externalStaticFileLocation` and `staticFileLocation`