# How does sparkjava(java webframe) auto refresh page

Tags: java, freemarker, spark-java

I`m new developper of spark, And now I was block by a issue.
I was implements freemarker as web template.
Not like other framework when you modify a .ftl file, You no need to restart the server.
But now in my local it must restart the server if I wanto see the change.
Below is code.

```
public class SparkServer {
public static void main(String[] args){
    get("/hello",(request,response) ->{
        Map root = new HashMap();
        root.put("user", "xiekakaban");
        Map product = new HashMap();
        product.put("name","Pringles");
        product.put("price",13.2);
        root.put("product",product);
        return new ModelAndView(root,"test.ftl");
    },FreeMarkerEngine.getInstance());
}
```

}

```
public class FreeMarkerEngine extends TemplateEngine{
private static FreeMarkerEngine freeMarkerEngine;
private Configuration freeConfig;

private FreeMarkerEngine() throws IOException{
    freeConfig = new Configuration();
    freeConfig.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(StringUtil.getResourceFile("templates"));
    freeConfig.setTemplateUpdateDelay(1);

}
public static FreeMarkerEngine getInstance(){
    if(freeMarkerEngine == null){
        try {
            freeMarkerEngine = new FreeMarkerEngine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    return freeMarkerEngine;
}
@Override
public String render(ModelAndView modelAndView) {
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    try {
        freeConfig.clearTemplateCache();
        freeConfig.clearSharedVariables();
        freeConfig.clearEncodingMap();
        Template template = freeConfig.getTemplate(modelAndView.getViewName());
        template.process(modelAndView.getModel(), stringWriter);
        System.out.println(stringWriter.toString());
        return stringWriter.toString();
    } catch (IOException | TemplateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "Can not find the template:"+modelAndView.getViewName();
}
```

}

I don`t sure whether it is cache by spark or freemarker.But I have clear freemarker cache.

Anyone can help me.....

Answer (score 0):

ok, I have figure out it.

[Reloading the static files in Spark/Jetty-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34358437/reloading-the-static-files-in-spark-jetty-server/35796389#35796389)

first I think you should make sure which page the freemarker load.
if you not setup, it will load ftl under "target" fold.

I think I put out a stupid question....